# Assigning many user to queue at once in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Is there any short method, through which we can assign hundreds of user's to a queue(exluding UI assignment) in one GO.

Regards
Chirag Verma

Answer (score 1):

You can add users to queues individually, but you can also add roles, territories, or public groups, which can add large numbers of users to the queue at once.  So if you've got a role set up like "West Coast Support Rep" then you can just add "West Coast Support Rep" to the "West Coast Queue" and all the users in that role will get added to the queue.

You can also use the tools in Setup for creating groups, and add the group to the queue.

Comment: same question then, can we add bulk of user's in a group through data loader. IF yes then please tell me.  Thanks

Comment: A queue is just a special form of a group.  If you look at the URL of a queue, you'll find its ID in there -- it'll be 15 chars and start with 00G, like 00G50000001EA8P.  In the Data Loader, you can create GroupMember rows with your queue's ID in the GroupId field and the user IDs in the UserOrGroupId field, and you can mass-add users that way also.